# Why Does FDT Show So Many Incorrect Errors and I Can't Compile

Tags: compilation, compiler-warnings, fdt

Sometimes when I use FDT, the editor shows errors on code which I think (sometimes know) is valid and I can't compile any projects.

Example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You **CAN** compile even if there are errors. FDT does not prevent compiling if it detects errors. If you know the syntax is correct, try to compile anyway.
2. FDT only guesses what will or won't be an error when you **DO** decide to compile.
3. The errors and warning FDT flags are completely customizable and can be turned off & on (pic below).

Some back story...

FDT is different from other editors because it has parser which scans your code and detects errors in it. This is different from an editor which relies on a compiler to show errors in the editor (e.g. JDT or Flash Builder). In fact, when using Haxe the errors and warnings FDT shows in the editor are directly from the Haxe compiler.

Sometimes there are bugs in the parser which incorrectly flag syntax as invalid - even though it is correct. This does not prevent you from compiling.

If you want to change what is / isn't flagged as an error, the parser can be adjusted here:
[image]